# Как получить экземпляр типа и его наследников?

Tags: c#, assembly

Пытаюсь получить по экземпляру типа и его наследников.

```
assembly.GetTypes()
          .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)) || t.IsEquivalentTo(typeof(T))))
          .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
          .OfType<T>()
```

Способа проще действительно нет? `IsSubclassOf` пропускает сам тип, а `IsAssignableFrom` почему то не возвращает наследников, хотя я может неправильно понял, что он делает.

Comment: `IsAssignableFrom` - проверяет что переменной одного проверяемого типа  можно присвоить значение типа параметра

Comment: Вы Generic типы пытаетесь найти?

Comment: @sp7, нет, просто метод Generic, для удобства использования. А создать пытаюсь экземпляр переданного типа и его наследников.

Comment: @Grundy т.е. работает наоборот, проверяя наследника убеждается, что общий тип присвоить нельзя? Тогда понятно, почему мне не подходит.

Comment: @Monk, почему не подходит? :-) если поменять местами параметры все начинает подходить :)

Comment: @Grundy `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t)` похоже действительно дает то, что мне надо. Можете оформить как ответ =)

Comment: :-D ну я не совсем понял вопрос, поэтому если вы сами нашли ответ можете ответить на собственный вопрос, желательно с описанием :)

Comment: @Grundy оформил и вспомнил, что свой ответ принять нельзя 2 дня :D всяко спасибо, разобрался заодно.

Comment: Ну так может кто еще ответит :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как подсказали в комментариях, [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx/css) помогает определить, можно ли присвоить экземпляр указанного типа экземпляру текущего типа. Таким образом, если вызывать его от базового типа:

```
typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t)
```

То получаются и сам тип и его наследники.
Итого, поиск выглядит чуть проще и понятнее:

```
assembly.GetTypes()
          .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && t.IsClass && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t))
          .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
          .OfType<T>()
```